# Mule - broker ClientId config

Tags: mule

I am using an activeMQ connector

```
 <jms:activemq-connector name="Active_MQ_1"  brokerURL="${amq.broker.url.1}"  eagerConsumer="true" numberOfConsumers="3" dynamicNotification="true" validateConnections="true" clientId="mule-server-01"  doc:name="Active MQ">
 <reconnect count="5" frequency="3000" blocking="false"/>
 </jms:activemq-connector>
```

Now if you see the "clientId" attribute above currently I have got that hardcoded. We are deploying the app in 2 servers and befopre a production deployment I have to manually change that to the corresponding machine's name.

Is there a way where I can use some SYS_ENV or some macro like $HOSTNAME which will automatically be replaced by the machine name once it gets deployed?

FYI - this client ID is useful as well can see the Consumers on the ActiveMQ Queue.

Thanks

Comment: Are you running you app in mule standalone?

Comment: Hi . Yes I am running Mule on Stand-alone. But I have 2 servers where I deploy the same app for resilience and load balancing over ActiveMQ Message broker

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use the same property resolver mechanism you use for the `brokerURL` attribute, ie. Spring's property resolver.

It allows you to do things like:

- Providing the value with a system property, so you can pass it from the command line.
- Overriding default value with an optional configuration file.

This gives you enough options to fit your production environment practices.

Comment: Thanks David. So I can define a property which will actually be a system variable? As this I want to take effect only when deployed and not during build phase so that it can pick up the machine name. Is there any System variable or macro I can use that way that you are aware of? something like $HostName etc. Thanks again

Comment: There is no standard Java system property that contains the hostname (see list here: http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/index.html?java/lang/System.html). You'll have to add the system property to whatever start-up command you use for Mule and get the value using whatever is relevant to your shell environment.